# What if someone I know provides an answer to a question?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

Suppose I am working in a team and I ask a question that is unanswered for a month or so, then someone from my team get the answer and posted that, or I got the answer and ask someone to post that. So is there any issue if the question and answer is posted by someone with the same IP, or if I ask someone on my team to post the answer?

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Oh hey, for once the Teams feature is justified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there are *some* issues with that:

1. Is it a good and on-topic question?
2. Is it actually a good answer to **the question as written**?
3. Is there overwhelming evidence that your accounts are from different persons and the cross-interactions are not a significant part of their usage?
4. Do you actually evaluate and act on each others contributions, when you see them, objectively (which *does* include reviewing, downvoting, closing, flagging and editing)?

Each and every one of those points contributes to SE's evaluation whether you are two independent users, a collective trying to subvert the voting-system, or just someone having a (more or less elaborate) sock.

Comment: what about " I got the answer and ask someone to post that"

Comment: Unless that someone is the person you got the answer from, he's willing to write a good answer, and the above points are fulfilled, desist. You can write a self-answer if it's a good on-topic question and you are capable and willing to write a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just answer to your own question, it'll help somone later.

And you will probably won the badge "[Self-Learner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) : Answer your own question with score of 3 or more"